# Replacing the struct's pack method

Tags: python, struct

I have the following code snippet:

```
def digest(self):
        mdi = self._counter & 0x3F
        length = struct.pack('!Q', self._counter<<3)

        if mdi < 56:
            padlen = 55-mdi
        else:
            padlen = 119-mdi

        r = self.copy()
        r.update('\x80'+('\x00'*padlen)+length)
        return ''.join([struct.pack('!L', i) for i in r._h[:self._output_size]])
```

I'm working on a project that doesn't use `CPython`, therefore I needed to replace the `struct` library with a native implementation. How can I implement the `struct.pack` method natively in Python?

Comment: This would be a narrower (and this more clearly topical) question if you only asked for to pack the specific data structures to need, not how to replace `pack` in general. One could interpret this as a request for someone to rewrite the entire standard library module in native Python for you, and that's clearly outside reasonable scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types). ! corresponds to big endian, while Q corresponds to a length of 8 bytes and unsigned (signed=False). Therefore, you could write

```
length = (self._counter<<3).to_bytes(8, 'big', signed=False)
```

Comment: Also, how can I replace the `struct.unpack('!16L', c)` method by an equivalent?

Comment: Similarly, use `int.from_bytes`. You’ll need to consult the struct documentation to learn about all the different format codes and options in order to generate the right equivalents.